# Cant Create Accout (Upload Image Swift)

Tags: firebase, authentication

After importing Firebase to my Project which i want to Create for iOS (Swift)
I tried to create a user, with ProfileImage and Username.
When i tap "Create Account" i get an error message it says "Error signing up".

This is the Error Message in the Terminal
2018-07-20 23:15:50.764062+0200 Collect App[3341:120860] [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

I will paste my code here.

```html
//
//  SignUpViewController.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    
  
   
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmuserPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dismissButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func tapToChangeProfileButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func handleDismissButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    
     var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController!
    private var authUser : User? {
        return Auth.auth().currentUser
    }
    
    public func sendVerificationMail() {
        if self.authUser != nil && !self.authUser!.isEmailVerified {
            self.authUser!.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
                // Notify the user that the mail has sent or couldn't because of an error.
            })
        }
        else {
            // Either the user is not available, or the user is already verified.
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openImagePicker))
        profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.height / 2
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        //tapToChangeProfileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openImagePicker), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @objc func openImagePicker(_ sender:Any) {
        // Open Image Picker
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    
    
    @IBAction func CreateAccount(_ sender: Any) {
     
        guard let username = userNameTextField.text else { return }
        guard let email = userEmailTextField.text else { return }
        guard let pass = userPasswordTextField.text else { return }
        guard let image = profileImageView.image else { return }
        
      
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass) { user, error in
            if error == nil && user != nil {
                print("User created!")
                
                
                // 1. Upload the profile image to Firebase Storage
                
                self.uploadProfileImage(image) { url in
                    
                    if url != nil {
                        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                        changeRequest?.displayName = username
                        changeRequest?.photoURL = url
                        
                        changeRequest?.commitChanges { error in
                            if error == nil {
                                print("User display name changed!")
                                
                                self.saveProfile(username: username, profileImageURL: url!) { success in
                                    if success {
                                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    } else {
                                        self.resetForm()
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                                self.resetForm()
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.resetForm()
                    }
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                self.resetForm()
            }
        }
    }
    func resetForm() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error signing up", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    
        func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url:URL?)->())) {
            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("user/\(uid)")
            
            // Create a reference to the file you want to download
            let starsRef = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")
            
            // Fetch the download URL
            starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    // Handle any errors
                } else {
                    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
                }
            }

        }
        func saveProfile(username:String, profileImageURL:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ success:Bool)->())) {
            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)")
            
            let userObject = [
                "username": username,
                "photoURL": profileImageURL.absoluteString
                ] as [String:Any]
            
            databaseRef.setValue(userObject) { error, ref in
                completion(error == nil)
            }
        }
        
    
    
    
    @IBAction func AlreadyaccountButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Already account Button Tapped")
        
        let LoginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        
        self.present(LoginViewController, animated: true)
        
    }
    
    
    //EmailVerificationViewController
    
    
    
    @IBAction func ResendEmailVerificationTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.sendVerificationMail()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func LoginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Login Button Tapped")
        
        let LoginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        
        self.present(LoginViewController, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    
  
    func displayMessage(userMessage:String) -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                    // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
                    print("Ok button tapped")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

  }
 }
}
extension SignUpViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            self.profileImageView.image = pickedImage
        }
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
}
```

Thanks for your time !

Now the New Code with another i error that i mentioned in the Comment

```html
@IBAction func CreateAccount(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let username = userNameTextField.text else { return }
        guard let image = profileImageView.image else { return }
        
      
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.userEmailTextField.text!, password: self.userPasswordTextField.text!) { user, error in
            if error == nil && user != nil {
                print("User created!")
                
                // 1. Upload the profile image to Firebase Storage
                
                self.uploadProfileImage(image, uid: user.uid) { url in
                    
                    if url != nil {
                        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                        changeRequest?.displayName = username
                        changeRequest?.photoURL = url
                        
                        changeRequest?.commitChanges { error in
                            if error == nil {
                                print("User display name changed!")
                                
                                self.saveProfile(username: username, profileImageURL: url!) { success in
                                    if success {
                                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    } else {
                                        self.resetForm()
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                                self.resetForm()
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.resetForm()
                    }
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                self.resetForm()
            }
        }
    }
    func resetForm() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error signing up", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    
    func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, uid:String, completion: @escaping ((_ url:URL?)->())) {
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("user/\(uid)")
        
        // Create a reference to the file you want to download
        let starsRef = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")
        
        // Fetch the download URL
        starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle any errors
            } else {
                // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your url is nil.
It is nil because you are creating the user, upon successful creation `self.uploadProfileImage(image)` is called in order to get the image url of the current user but the user is not logged in.

A solution would be:
Sign in the user and upon success then call `uploadProfileImage`.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, Could you check now the new SignUpViewController that  i also show now, Because it didnt worked it says

Extra argument 'uid' in call

Comment: Yes because you didnt add the argument to your function, i have added the code showing how `uploadProfileImage` should be. Try signing up a new user with a new email address and tell me what happens.

Comment: now Look at the new Code because now it says 

Value of type 'AuthDataResult?' has no member 'uid'

At the line of "self.uploadProfileImage(image, uid: user.uid) { url in"

Thanks for your time

Comment: make it `self.uploadProfileImage(image, uid: user.user.uid)`

Comment: I tried to do that . But when I type it Xcode suggested me another code line. and with the suggested code line it also dont work.
self.uploadProfileImage(image, uid: (user?.user.uid)!)

Comment: edited(again) revert your uploadProfileImage back to how it was but, login the user and upon success then call it.

Comment: Use your initial code and login the user to Firebase before you call uploadProfileImage

Comment: so he cant upload an image at the SignUp screen only later when he already logged in?

Comment: According to your code the currentUser is needed in order to upload an image, so the user needs to be logged in, take the email and password and use it for the login. I would strongly recommend you read the documentation.